# How can i make two separate sqs queue in same ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I am using EC2 and SQS, how can i make two separate sqs queue in same ec2 instance. Let's say the case like - I am using sqs to process my task in queue and each task takes little long time and suddenly i got a requirement where i have to process 50k queue process which will take minimum 1 weak, here i want to make a new queue thread for this 50k messages so that it should not let other coming queue to wait until it get processed. so that main thread dont get delay for new coming messaged

Answer (score 1):

You question doesn't quite read correctly because SQS Queues do not belong to EC2 instances, Queues are created at an account level, and EC2 instance can use the AWSSDK client to create queues as needed.

From what you are saying, one approach to handle a sudden burst of messages in a queue would be to keep the messages in 1 queue, and define an EC2 Auto Scaling Group configured to scale up and down EC2 instance base on the queue length. [See here for instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html)

Alternatively, if this queue has messages that need to be separated because a back pressure of one message type shouldn't impact the other, then you should create multiple queues (either using the console or SDK) and poll these independently. You could poll from multiple threads, poll from 1 thread and fan the work out to multiple threads, poll from multiple processed, or use completely different EC2 instances to poll from. You have a lot of options open to you here.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer it is really helpful for me.

How can i create multiple queues in one account . . ?

I have to put message through API. so if i create multiple message queue do i get any queue id to identify which queue i have to push message ? 



Please Help

Comment: Yes, when you create your queue, in the response will be a QueueUrl property. When you went a message, you include the same property to tell the client which queue to send it to.